# How to code in swift using google tag manager v5 especially for the enhanced ecommerce part?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to using gtm v5 for Swift, but i found that it is not working.

It is not sending any data to Google Analytics, but at the same time it doesn't give me errors. I already double check the GTM and everything are the same with the one at the Google Tag Manager documentation.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let  product1 : [String : Any] = [
        AnalyticsParameterItemID : "sku1234", // ITEM_ID or ITEM_NAME is required.
        AnalyticsParameterItemName : "Android Jogger Sweatpants",
        AnalyticsParameterItemCategory : "Apparel/Men/Pants",
        AnalyticsParameterItemVariant : "Blue",
        AnalyticsParameterItemBrand : "Google",
        AnalyticsParameterPrice : 39.99,
        AnalyticsParameterCurrency : "USD",  // Item-level currency unused today.
        AnalyticsParameterQuantity : 1
    ]

    let items : Array = [product1]

    let ecommerce : [String : Any] = [
        "items" : items,
        "screenName" : "Thank you page",
        AnalyticsParameterItemList : "Search Results", // List name.
        AnalyticsParameterTransactionID : "T12345",
        AnalyticsParameterAffiliation : "Google Store - Online",
        AnalyticsParameterValue : 75.98, // Revenue.
        AnalyticsParameterTax : 3.80,
        AnalyticsParameterShipping : 5.34,
        AnalyticsParameterCurrency : "USD",
        AnalyticsParameterCoupon : "SUMMER2017"
    ]

    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventEcommercePurchase, parameters: ecommerce)

    print("Success!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured tag according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases), *Enhanced Ecommerce Features* should be set to *true*:

```
Tag Type: Universal Analytics 
Track Type: Screen View
Enhanced Ecommerce Features: True
Read data from: Firebase
Event Trigger, e.g.: (Custom > Some Events) Event Name equals ecommerce_purchase
```